# Are there any vegetables that can reduce body fat?

Tags: health, weight-management, vegetables

What vegetables can reduce body fat?

I'm not focussed on workouts or meal plans.

Some people say curry leaves, garlic etc. are there any more foods known to have this property?

Answer (score 5):

All vegetables can help reduce body fat, IF they are consumed as part of a calorie-controlled diet. The only way to reduce body fat is to maintain a calorific deficit. Therefore, substituting high-calorie foods with low calorie foods such as vegetables, has the potential to reduce body fat.

However, simply adding vegetables to your diet [will not result in body fat loss](https://doi.org/10.3945/ajcn.114.090548).

There are many claims that grapefruit, green tea and curry leaves act as "fat burners" but I have not been able to find any any peer-reviewed research which shows that any vegetables can promote fat-loss on their own, except for [Fujioka et all (2006)](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/jmf.2006.9.49?journalCode=jmf&), which did find evidence for grapefruit promoting weight loss in obese adults, however my university does not have free access to this journal (which I have never heard of actually).

References:

Kaiser, Kathryn A., et al. "Increased fruit and vegetable intake has no discernible effect on weight loss: a systematic review and meta-analysis–." The American journal of clinical nutrition 100.2 (2014): 567-576

Fujioka, Ken, et al. "The effects of grapefruit on weight and insulin resistance: relationship to the metabolic syndrome." Journal of medicinal food 9.1 (2006): 49-54.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about vegetables but Lemons are a good for the purpose. Drinking some water infused with lemon slices every morning can be good to lose weight.

*Disclaimer: Not saying this will work for everyone, just worth a try.*

Comment: Hello. Welcome to the Vegetarianism SE. In general, when posting an answer to a question like this, it would be good if you provided some evidence for your claims. It does not need to be peer reviewed research paper, just a source for the information you provide which can be followed up on if people want to. It helps us to avoid opinionated and unsubstantiated answers in the long run. You might find that if your answer lacks this background it will get downvoted by the community.